# How to answer a question that the terminal gives you?

Tags: vmware, vmware-workstation

I am new to Ubuntu. I installed it on a virtual machine. I am trying to install VMware tools, but when I type in `sudo ./vmware-install.pl -d` the terminal gives me a the below question. I don't know how to say yes or no.

[image]

Comment: `yes | sudo ./vmware-install.pl -d` should work too ;)

Answer (score 3):

Just type your answer and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>!

Typically, the system will accept `yes`/`y` for "yes" or `no` / `n` for "no", but this may differ based on the system and the program you're setting up.

Any answer in brackets (like in your image) is the "default" option and will be selected automatically if you just hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Alternatively, if you see things like `[y/N]`, it means that the default is `n` or `no`, but you can override if you need to.

Comment: Ok but when I type yes the terminal just fills up with the letter y and nothing happens

Comment: You need to type it at the prompt when it asks for it, not at your regular terminal. `yes` is also a command that spams `y` into your terminal, as you've seen.

Comment: I am so sorry but I don't know how to do that. I know I may sound like a retard but I just installed Ubuntu and before I hadn't even seen it.

Comment: You type `y` or whatnot when you see the "Do you want still want to..." text from the VMware installer.